# Mongoose pre hook for remove method is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two separate models: Post and Comment. The Comment model has a field called 'post' which refers to a post object. I'm using `pre` hook in the post model to delete all the comments associated with the post. I'm trying to delete a post from the client side, but only the post itself gets deleted, not the comments. I'm unable to figure out why this is happening.

This is the hook from post model

```
postSchema.pre("remove", async function (next) {
  try {
    const commentIds = this.comments.map((comment) => comment.toString());
    await this.model("Comment").deleteMany({
      _id: {
        $in: commentIds,
      },
    });
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

and this is the route callback function

```
const deletePost = async (req, res) => {
  try {
 
    await Post.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id);

    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Post deleted successfully",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: "Error deleting post",
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: try `findByIdAndDelete` method with `pre("findOneAndDelete")` pre hook.

Comment: @sachin I don't think that works because you can only use specific methods in the pre-hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`Model.findByIdAndRemove()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/5.x/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove) documentation:

> This function triggers the following middleware. `findOneAndRemove()`

So you should use `schema.pre('remove')` hook. One use case of the pre middleware is:

> removing dependent documents (removing a user removes all their blogposts)

And,

> In mongoose 5.x, instead of calling `next()` manually, you can use a function that returns a promise. In particular, you can use `async/await`.

Besides, the elements of `this.comments` are all instances of `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` class. You can pass the `this.comments` as the value of `$in` operator directly.

The below statement is unnecessary

```
const commentIds = this.comments.map((comment) => comment.toString())
```

Mongoose also support implicit `$in`:

> Because of schemas, Mongoose knows what types fields should be, so it can provide some neat syntactic sugar. For example, if you forget to put `$in` on a non-array field, Mongoose will add `$in` for you.

Shorter way:

`models/post.js`:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  comments: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'comment'
  }]
});

PostSchema.pre('remove', async function () {
  await this.model('comment').deleteMany({ _id: this.comments })
})

export default mongoose.model('post', PostSchema);
```

`models/comment.js`:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  content: String,
});

export default mongoose.model('comment', CommentSchema);
```

`main.js`:

```js
import Post from './models/post';
import Comment from './models/comment';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { config } from '../../src/config';

mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false });
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', async () => {
  try {
    // seed
    // @ts-ignore
    const comments = await Comment.create([{ content: 'comment a' }, { content: 'comment b' }])
    const post = new Post({ title: 'post a', comments });
    await post.save();

    // test
    const postDoc = await Post.findOne({ title: 'post a' })
    await postDoc.remove();

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    db.close();
  }
})
```

Execution result:

```bash
Mongoose: comments.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("646338b558d2f850c15d80de"), content: 'comment a', __v: 0}, { session: null })
Mongoose: comments.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("646338b558d2f850c15d80df"), content: 'comment b', __v: 0}, { session: null })
Mongoose: posts.insertOne({ comments: [ ObjectId("646338b558d2f850c15d80de"), ObjectId("646338b558d2f850c15d80df") ], _id: ObjectId("646338b558d2f850c15d80e2"), title: 'post a', __v: 0}, { session: null })
Mongoose: posts.findOne({ title: 'post a' }, { projection: {} })
this.comments:  ["646338b558d2f850c15d80de","646338b558d2f850c15d80df"]
[true,true]
Mongoose: comments.deleteMany({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("646338b558d2f850c15d80de"), ObjectId("646338b558d2f850c15d80df") ] }}, {})
Mongoose: posts.deleteOne({ _id: ObjectId("646338b558d2f850c15d80e2") }, RemoveOptions { session: null })
```

package version: `"mongoose": "^5.11.9"`